# Bluetooth PAN issue

Tags: bluetooth, connection-issues

I have to setup the bluetooth PAN on my development board. On my device most of the functions working fine -- but PAN is having problem.

I am tring to set up Static IP for my board , which will be a client. My master is set up on the Ubuntu 12.04 PC.

I can make the connection via `pand`:

```
pand -c <bt address of the ubuntu PC>
```

<sup>[my master is working in GM mode]</sup>

To bring up the `bnep` interface below are my commands:

```
netcfg bnep0 up
ifconfig bnep0 172.22.22.10 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

but still I can not ping the master and client from master.

Do i need to do any other setting?

Thanks
Robin